# Generic Interpolation for many types in C#

Tags: c#, generics, unity3d, interpolation

I made a generic interpolator for Unity objects, but the way it functions makes me question if there's a better way to approach this problem.

I want the logic inside of the `Tween<T>` function to be the same for every type. I don't want to create many overrides for unique types because that would cause a lot of pointless code duplication.

The biggest "code smell" I can see is in the `LerpFunction<T>` where I am switching based on the type, and also casting things back and forth like a madman. Is there a better pattern which lets me accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
public class Tweener
{
    public static IEnumerator Tween<T>(T startValue, T endValue, float duration, Action<T> setter)
    {
        var startTime = Time.time;
        setter(startValue);
        while (Time.time - startTime < duration)
        {
            var t = (Time.time - startTime) / duration;
            t = Mathf.Clamp(t, 0f, 1f);

            var currentValue = LerpFunction(startValue, endValue, t);
            setter(currentValue);
            yield return null;
        }
        setter(endValue);
    }

    private static T LerpFunction<T>(T a, T b, float t)
    {
        return a switch
        {
            float => (T)(object)Mathf.Lerp((float)(object)a, (float)(object)b, t),
            Vector3 => (T)(object)Vector3.Lerp((Vector3)(object)a, (Vector3)(object)b, t),
            Quaternion => (T)(object)Quaternion.Slerp((Quaternion)(object)a, (Quaternion)(object)b, t),
            Color => (T)(object)Color.Lerp((Color)(object)a, (Color)(object)b, t),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Cannot interpolate function of type {typeof(T)}")
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's refactor it in 3 simple steps

#### Step 1: Use type pattern matching and `when`

- We can use the type pattern matching capability of switch expression
- By specifying names (`lhs` and `rhs`) the casting will be done

  - automatically for `lhs`
  - and semi-automatically for `rhs`

```
private static T LerpFunction<T>(T a, T b, float t)
=> a switch
{
    float lhs when b is float rhs => (T)(object)Math.Lerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    Vector3 lhs when b is Vector3 rhs => (T)(object)Vector3.Lerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    Quaternion lhs when b is Quaternion rhs => (T)(object)Quaternion.Slerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    Color lhs when b is Color rhs => (T)(object)Color.Lerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Cannot interpolate function of type {typeof(T)}")
};
```

#### Step 2: Use `ValueTuple`

- We can branch based on multiple variables by putting them into a `ValueTuple`

```
private static T LerpFunction<T>(T a, T b, float t)
=> (a, b) switch
{
    (float lhs, float rhs) => (T)(object)Math.Lerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    (Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs) => (T)(object)Vector3.Lerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    (Quaternion lhs, Quaternion rhs) => (T)(object)Quaternion.Slerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    (Color lhs, Color rhs) => (T)(object)Color.Lerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Cannot interpolate function of type {typeof(T)}")
};
```

#### Step 3: Restrict `T` to `struct`

- If you could restrict `T` is a `struct` then you could get rid of the `(T)(object)` castings as well

```
private static T LerpFunction<T>(T a, T b, float t) where T: struct
=> (a, b) switch
{
    (float lhs, float rhs) => Math.Lerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    (Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs) => Vector3.Lerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    (Quaternion lhs, Quaternion rhs) => Quaternion.Slerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    (Color lhs, Color rhs) => Color.Lerp(lhs, rhs, t),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Cannot interpolate function of type {typeof(T)}")
};
```

---

Final though: I would suggest to prefer `NotSupportedException` rather than `NotImplementedException`, because the latter is misleading. If someone calls it with `double`s at the first time, then (s)he won't call the method again since it it not implemented.